# How to check whether a JSON key's value is an array or not if you don't know the key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do I check whether a value in an JSON key's value is an array if you don't know the key's name?
I may receive 2 different formats of a JSON object:

```
 {
    "person": [{
            "id": "1",
            "x": "abc",
            "attributes": ["something"]
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "x": "abc"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Depending on the format I will parse it differently. My goal is to create an if statement that would detect whether the value of the key is an Array or just a value, without knowing the name of the key (in above code let's assume I don't really know the name of "attributes"). How do I achieve that? Not only do I have to loop through all person objects, but also all of it's keys.

I found a solution that does that knowing the name of the attribute and there's just one object "person", but don't know how to build on that with multiple "person" objects and not knowing the name of the key?

```
if (Array.isArray(json.person['attributes'])) // assuming I hold the JSON in json var and I parse it with JSON.parse
    {

    }
```

Comment: Will there be more than these 3 keys? If you have only 3 keys, you could do destructuring with `rest`. `const { id, x, ...rest } = personObject; console.log(Object.values(rest)[0])`

Comment: It sounds like something Object.values() should solve.

Comment: Yes, let's assume we don't also know the number of keys in person object. It may be 3, it may be 300.

Comment: If you have 300 properties, which exact property do you want to check for an array? If any of them is an array? If all the properties are arrays?

Comment: All of them, I'd need to loop through them

Comment: Something like this?: `Object.values(person).every(v => Array.isArray(v))` (Here `person` refers to an object. Not an array as mentioned in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Data payload:

```
const payload =  {
    person: [
        {
            id: 1,
            x: 'abc',
            attributes: ['something']
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            x: 'abc'
        }
    ]
};
```

Function that will return if some entry has an Array as value:

```
const arrayEntries = json => {

    let response = [{
        isArray: false,
        jsonKey: null,
        jsonValue: null
    }];

    Object.entries(json).map(entry => {
        if (Array.isArray(entry[1])) {
            response.push({
                isArray: true,
                jsonKey: entry[0],
                jsonValue: entry[1]
            });
        }
    });

    return response;
}
```

Usage example:

```
payload.person.map(person => {
    console.log(arrayEntries(person));
});
```

Return will be something like this:

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/WIS-Graphics/pen/ExjVPEz

---

**ES5 Version:**

```
function arrayEntries(json) {

    var response = [{
        isArray: false,
        jsonKey: null,
        jsonValue: null
    }];

    Object.entries(json).map(function(entry) {
        if (Array.isArray(entry[1])) {
            response.push({
                isArray: true,
                jsonKey: entry[0],
                jsonValue: entry[1]
            });
        }
    });

    return response;
}

payload.person.map(function(person) {
    console.log(arrayEntries(person));
});
```

[image]

Comment: Any chance this could be written in a standard (non-arrow) syntax? It doesn't seem to work on the console I have on server :(

Comment: Sure, there you have an ES5 version. Check my answer update.